# is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE TempdataDB 
SET discountPrice = price - (
   SELECT (
      SELECT '10.75' / (
         SELECT count(*) FROM TempdataDB
      )
   ) / quantity FROM TempdataDB
)
```

result same ERROR ... ANY help ?

Comment: Can you explain what do you want to do?

Comment: i have 10 rows into TempDataDB with price and quantity. I want to apply a 10,75 $ discount to all rows and update into discountPrice coll

Comment: For that you would to do: `update tempdatadb set discountprice = price - 10.75;`

Comment: NO ... because i have quantity on product and this price is for 1 quantity

Comment: Please add some example data to your question. Just a few rows will be of great help.

Comment: https://ibb.co/4Jhc9GC

Comment: What's the expected `discountPrice` for the first two rows?

Comment: the discountPrice is ""Pret/Discount" coll for 1 quantity

Comment: Oh... I think what you want to do is to apply a $10.75 discount to the whole "order". This is an order with 10 items in it, and you want to **distribute** the discount into the separate items. Is that it?

Comment: yes, true and need to calculate into mysql

Comment: Then, this is not possible in MySQL. You'll need to retrieve the rows to your application, dsitribute the discount (taking care of rounding differences) and update the rows back into the table. No way around it in MySQL.

Comment: Thank for help .... Merry Christmas !